# Distributional derivative of $\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, functional-analysis, analysis, distribution-theory

For $x\in\mathbb{R}^3$ we have $\frac{1}{|x|} \in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $\frac{1}{|x|} \to 0$ as $|x| \to \infty$. Hence we can conclude that
$$
f(x)=\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}
$$
defines a (tempered) distribution
$$
\phi \mapsto \int_{\mathbb{R}^3}f\phi.
$$
For a distribution $T \in \mathcal{S}'(\mathbb{R}^3)$ its derivative is defined as $(\partial x_i T)\phi = -T(\partial x_i \phi)$.

Now I want to calculate the partial distributional derivative of $f$. Starting with the definition yields

$$
-\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}\partial x_i \phi(x) dx
$$

But how do I proceed? Since $f$ has a singularitie in $0$ there could somewhere appear a delta function.

Comment: use chain rule  and the fact taht $ d|x|=sing(x)$ where $ sign(x)=1 $ if $ x>0$ and -1 otherwise

Comment: I'd switch to spherical coordinates, exclude the singularity with an $\epsilon$ ball around the origin, integrate by parts, bound terms, and then let $\epsilon$ approach zero.

Comment: Note that having only $L^1_{loc}$ is not sufficient to define a tempered distribution, you need some additional argument; here they decay on infinity would be enough.

Comment: @TZakrevskiy yes, you are right. I will correct it in the above text

Comment: @runner.87 I tried to use spherical coordinates, but I don't know how to 'transform' the partial derivative ...

Comment: I think that chain rule, the rule for fractions, and the identity $\nabla |x|=\frac{x}{|x|}$ are quite sufficient here.

Comment: It seems that the usual pointwise differentiation is enough to compute the distributional derivative. You only begin to see Dirac-delta-thingly for second derivatives and higher ones. If you are not convinced, apply the 2nd Green's identity to write $$ -\int_{\Bbb{R}^3\setminus B_{\epsilon}} \frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}\partial_k \varphi \, dx = \int_{\partial B_{\epsilon}} \left( \frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}\hat{x}_k \right) \varphi \cdot d\sigma_x + \int_{\Bbb{R}^3\setminus B_{\epsilon}} \varphi \nabla \cdot \left( \frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}\hat{x}_k \right) \, dx $$ and take the limit as $\epsilon \to 0$.

Comment: Ah ok, your approach with the green identity seems to work. Just for an complete unterstanding: I now the Green identities and the formula for integration by parts only for bounded domains with lipschitz continuous boundary. But here $\Bbb{R}^3\setminus B_{\epsilon}$ is an unbounded domain ...

Comment: And a second question: For $f(x)=\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}$ and the associated distribution $L_f$ we obtained that the distributional derivative coincide with the pointwise derivative. Does that mean that $\partial_{x_j}L_f=L_{\partial_{x_j}f}$? I'm just a bit confused since when we differentiate $f$ pointwise we get a $|x|^{-3}$ in the denominator and this is not integrable in $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$-\int_{\mathbb{R}^3}\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}\partial_j \phi(x) \,dx = -\left ( \lim_{\epsilon \to 0} \int_{\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B_\epsilon}\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}\partial_j \phi(x) \,dx \right )$$
by dominated convergence. Use the [formula for integration by parts in higher dimensions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts#Higher_dimensions) to obtain
$$
\int_{\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus B_\epsilon}\frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|}\partial_j \phi(x) \,dx = \int_{\partial B_{\epsilon}} \frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|} \phi(x) \nu_j \,dS(x) - \int_{\Bbb{R}^3\setminus B_{\epsilon}} \phi(x) \partial_j  \frac{e^{i|x|}}{|x|} \,dx.
$$
The integration over the unbounded domain is justified because a surface integral of $f\phi$ over $\partial B_R$ would thend to zero for $\phi \in \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^3)$ and $R \to \infty$.
The first integral on the RHS goes to zero since $|\nu_j| \leq 1$ and the area of the surface of $\partial B_{\epsilon}$ is $4\pi\epsilon^2$.
Further, for $x \neq 0$ we have
$$
\partial_j f(x)=\frac{x_je^{i|x|}(i|x|-1)}{|x|^3},
$$
which has an integrable singularity in $0$. Hence one can conclude that
$$
\partial_j L_f=L_{\partial_jf}.
$$